# Workflow Push to deploy, Production Server, GitHub, .env.php in Laravel

Tags: git, laravel, github

I'm building a workflow for push to deploy in Laravel.

Sensitive Information like Database-Credentials are stored in my `/.env.php`.

Now I have an uplink to the repo of my vServer, so I can use `git push vServer` to deploy my application.

This is not a problem.

But now I want to push to GitHub too with `git push github`.
The problem is that my `/.env.php` gets pushed to github too, so everyone can see my sensitive information.

How to integrate a workflow so that my sensitive information doesn't get pushed to github? Is there any way I can tell git that it shouldn't push my `/.env.php` to github?

Sure, 1 solution would be to use environment variables on the server without using `/.env.php` in my project, but I think you all agree that this isn't the best solution.

Comment: I forgot to mention: The same applies to every sensitive file like Stripe API Keys etc..

Answer (score 0):

The environment file should never be checked into GIT. use the `.gitignore` file in the root directory to ignore it. (Obviously now you have to remove it from GIT first)

```
/vendor
/node_modules
.env.php
```

You then will have to create or upload the `.env.php` on every new environment manually but that shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: No, I want to use push to deploy without having to create files manually on the server.

Comment: It depends on how your deploy actually works but you should be able to only need to create the file once. That's the whole purpose of a environment file it is only stored locally on the machine

Comment: No, I dont want to create and edit all my sensitive files manually on the server. I want to create and edit them on my local machine and i want to be able to push them to the production server, whereby the sensitive files don't get pushed to my public github repo.

Comment: As far as I know when you use git to push your changes to the server they have to be in your repository.